# Azure Function Apps - PowerShell's ErrorActionPreference

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

By default the environment's $ErrorActionPreference is set to '**Continue**'. When a cmdlet throws an error the script will continue.

I want it to '**Stop**' and get caught in the catch of my try-catch block. In my script I am able to set:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
```

and if I print the value to the screen I can see that  it is now set to '**Stop**' and not '**Continue**'. However, when my cmdlet throws an error it still continues. It is ignoring my error action preference and behaving according to the default value.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: have you tried invoking the actual command with `-erroractionpreference`? maybe that will work?

Comment: I think the parameter is -ErrorAction and it doesn't make a difference. Tried -ErrorActionPreference just to see, but no joy. The same script works as expected on my own machine. However, once it runs in a Function App the ErrorActionPreference appears to be always "Continue" even if I explicitly change it to "Stop".

Comment: yeah, sorry, `-erroraction`. sad that it didn't help. no clue, then :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I'm not sure what you are doing, but for me it works correctly:

```
Write-Output "PowerShell Timer trigger function executed at:$(get-date)";

try {
    Get-Process 'hh' -erroraction stop
}
catch{
    Write-Output "caught"
    exit
}

Write-Output "never reached"
```

or like this:

```
Write-Output "PowerShell Timer trigger function executed at:$(get-date)";
$global:erroractionpreference = 1
try {
    Get-Process 'hh'
}
catch{
    Write-Output "caught"
    exit
}

Write-Output "i do not work"
```

Both print the same (except for timestamp, ofc):

> 2017-02-02T19:56:35.916 PowerShell Timer trigger function executed
>   at:02/02/2017 19:56:35
>
> 2017-02-02T19:56:35.933 caught
>
> 2017-02-02T19:56:35.933 Function completed (Success,
>   Id=6097f1bf-06e1-4a1d-ba27-392607d9b33c)

Comment: It worked! I needed $global:erroractionpreference = 1 and not $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'.  Thanks very much :)